# Salary increase for research assistant in Germany

Tags: university, germany

As per oeffentlicher-dienst the salary of TVL employee is increased, and we are supposed to get some allowance from June 2023, but I have not got any increment. https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/tvoed/tr/2023/

Do I understand anything wrong information?

Comment: The page you linked is concerned with TVöD rather than TV-L. The correct one is [here](https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/tv-l/tr/).

Comment: And the page that @Watercrystal links to in turn links to the most recent bargaining agreement [here](https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/tv-l/tr/2021/), where it looks like if you are on TV-L, your last salary increase was in December 2022, with no further increases planned until the end of the current agreement on September 30, 2023. So: are you sure you are on TVÖD? If so, you should probably indeed get an increase, but sometimes this takes a while, and then you get the back pay in a later month.

Comment: @StephanKolassa thanks for clearing, my bad, I am TVL at university as research assistant

Comment: @Watercrystal thanks, I am talking about TVL, will there be any increase in salary after September like TVOD?